# SQL compare two max Dates from the same table

Tags: sql, sql-server, max

I dont know how to call this topic so I thought I just would explain what I need. 
I have the following table:

```
Id  IdPerson  date        successfully
1   1         01.01.2012  FALSE
2   1         01.01.2014  TRUE
3   2         01.01.2014  FALSE
```

Now I want all IdPerson where the newest entry is FALSE
So that would be just IdPerson 2 because IdPerson 1 is true in 2014.

I really have no clue how to do that.

Can somebody help me?

Greets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an interesting approach to this that uses conditional aggregation:

```
select idperson
from table t
group by idperson
having max(date) = max(case when successfully = 'false' then date end);
```

Note:  this solution (as well as the others) assume that `date` is stored in a native date/time format.  If not, you should fix the database, but this query would need to use `convert()`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ...)` in a subquery to locate the newest entry per person. Then, in the outer query, select only those having `successfully = 'FALSE'`:

```
SELECT Id,  IdPerson,  [date]
FROM (
  SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY IdPerson ORDER BY [date] DESC) AS rn,
         *
  FROM MyTable ) t
WHERE t.rn = 1 AND t.successfully = 'FALSE'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL Server 2008 R2 (or higher), then you can use Apply

```
select p.* from Person P
cross Apply
(
    select MAX(date) [maxdate] from Person group by Id
)a
where P.Date = a.maxdate and p.Successfully = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried this in mysql:

SELECT Id,IdPerson,date,Status from MyTable
 WHERE status='false' AND date= ALL( SELECT max(date) from MyTable
   GROUP BY IdPerson);